# Detect/Parse 00:00:00 (without date) to Datetime

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

In one of my applications i'm recieving a `date` as `string` from the server.

examples:

```
2014-04-04 00:00:00
2013-05-07 13:00:36
2014-05-03
2014-02-01-07:00:00 '(obviously not a valid datetimeformat but thats been handled further inside the code)
00:00:00 'The null-date (meaning NULL is the value inside the database)
```

its the null-date that is giving me headaches. Because if I try to `parse` that `{00:00:00}` that `datetime` I always get the date of `today` and `not the DateTime.Minvalue`

Code example:

```
    Dim i As DateTime
    i = DateTime.Parse(i)
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmm:ss")) 'Returns 2014-07-14 00:00:00
    Console.ReadLine()
```

I would like to achieve any of the results below:

1. Using `no Regex` how can i detect the presence (or absence) of the date-component to detect the null-date
2. How can i cast my `null-date (00:00:00)` to datetime where the output of the parse is either `DateTime.MinValue` Or `nothing`.

I know the solution may be easy, but i just keep on missing it. I would greatly appreciate any solutions or advice concerning this issue.

**Note:** The software is quite old and still runs under `.Net 2.0`

**Note:** A valid datetime **may** contain "00:00:00" so `String.Contains` is out of the question.

Comment: Why not just use equality? Check whether the string *equals* "00:00:00" and handle that differently.

Comment: That solutions is ridiculously simple. Why haven't i thought about that? Except your given solution (which by the way is excellent) is there (at all) any possibillity to cast it to datetime.minvalue?

Comment: What Jon Skeet said, but strip whitespace around the string before the comparison by using the `Trim` function. PS: As for casting it to DateTime.MinValue, just assign the value you want like `If Trim(MyString) = "00:00:00" Then MyDate = DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `NoCurrentDateDefault`, like the help for `DateTime.Parse` suggests ;-)

```
i = DateTime.Parse("00:00:00", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault)
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> The string to be parsed can take any of the following forms:
>
> - ...
> - A string with a time but no date component. The method assumes the current date unless you call the Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles) overload and include DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault in the styles parameter, in which case the method assumes January 1, 0001.

Comment: sweet exactly what i needed! Cheers mate!